# Xamarin forms connect to a ASMX webservice

Tags: web-services, xamarin, asmx

I am trying to make a Xamarin forms project that gets data from an ASMX Webservice

This is the code I am using

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://mobile.xn--schller-golf-xjb.dk/WebServices/IndoorServices.asmx/IndoorBruttoGns");

string soapstr = string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
        <soap:Body>
            < IndoorBruttoGns xmlns = ""http://mobile.xn--schller-golf-xjb.dk/WebServices"" />
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>");

var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://mobile.xn--schller-golf-xjb.dk/WebServices/IndoorServices.asmx/IndoorBruttoGns", new StringContent(soapstr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return content;
```

The Webservice doesn't need any input but I get a 500 internal server error and I know the Webservice works because I call it from a PhoneGap project using $.ajax

Comment: you need to look at the server logs to determine what is causing the 500

Comment: plus, I would check if in your PhoneGap project you are adding a UserAgent or something else to your request